# logged user id from session

Tags: php, session

Hello i want to insert into database logged u_id in php..i use session($_SESSION['u_id']) to get it but sometime it will go wrong.is it safe and good to use session or good to pass from url ??

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy. Once the user logs in, you should set a session like

```
$_SESSION['user']=1; //if the user's id is 1, for example
```

To check whether the user is logged, use

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
//user has logged in
}else{
//user has not logged in
}
```

At the beginning of both files you should write `sesssion_start()`

Comment: +1 for writing the code out :)

Comment: use session_start() on each page you want to have access to session variables !

Comment: no one understand my question.....I want to say which way is good and safe .....passing u_id in URL or store u_id in session ????

Comment: passing it through session is highly insecure... you could change its value and log in as a different user

Comment: oops, sorry... I meant "passing it through URL is highly insecure"...

Answer (score 0):

When you confirm the user login use `session_start();` and set a variable such as `$loggedIn=true;

On each page, check the `$loggedIn` to see if it is there and set to true.